# Alert on unload

Tags: javascript

i need to close windows show the alert box but in my code every time will ask automatic alert box using onbeforeunload function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) {
        var message = 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
        if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
            evt = window.event;
        }       
        if (evt) {
            evt.returnValue = message;
        }
        return message;
    } 
</script>


<form action="test.php">
    <input name="sample" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I realise that english is not your first language but it is very unclear what you want to do. Can you try to rephrase the question?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are willing to show the message only one time. Global vars are very undesirable but this will do the trick.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var alertWasShown = false;
        window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) {
            if (alertWasShown)
                return;
            var message = 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
            if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
                evt = window.event;
            }       
            if (evt) {
                evt.returnValue = message;
            }
            alertWasShown = true;
            return message;
        } 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `form` is actually leaving the page.... you need to stop the `onbeforeunload` or trigger only when you want with a conditional var.

Example with your code:

### SCRIPT

```
   var response = true; // true by default

   window.onbeforeunload = function(evt) {
      if(response){
         var message = 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
         if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
            evt = window.event;
         }       
         if (evt) {
            evt.returnValue = message;
         }
         return message;
      }
   }

   function validateForm(){
      // form validation process...
      response = false;
   }
```

### HTML

```
<form action="test.php" onsubmit="validateForm()">
   <input name="sample" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```